# flake8 and "old style class declaration"

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I use `flake8` to check formatting of my python3 scripts. When I declare classes like this...

```
class MyClass:
```

...I get a warning "H238 -- old style class declaration, use new style (inherit from `object`)".

However, the documentation clearly has declarations just like this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax

I think that inheriting from `object` looks unnecessarily cluttered. Is it functionally different? The documentation doesn't say anything about inheriting from `object`.

Is this a bug with `flake8`, or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: flake8 needs to support both python2 and python3, and the error you're seeing is a python2-ism. Just disable that particular check in your flake8 configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation says](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/):

> It is **very** important to install **Flake8** on the *correct* version of Python for your needs. If you want **Flake8** to properly parse new language features in Python 3.5 (for example), you need it to be installed on 3.5 for **Flake8** to understand those features. In many ways, **Flake8** is tied to the version of Python on which it runs.